# How to view all tables in CQL and CQLSH?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I'm trying to explore the database and want to see all tables that exist there. What's the command that's equivalent to `SHOW TABLES;` in SQL?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

to get all table names : `DESC tables;`

to get detailed view of a table : `DESC table <table_name>;`

to get detailed view of all tables in a keyspace : `DESC keyspace <keyspace_name>;`

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can use the `DESCRIBE` command:

```
DESCRIBE tables;
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the version of Cassandra, the following may work for you

```
SELECT * FROM system_schema.tables
```

Check out the other tables in the system_schema keyspace to see what other info you can get